# H2 database , does not save changes on shutdown

Tags: java, h2

I am using H2 with Hibernate 4.1 ORM as JPA 2.

This is my database URL from persistance.xml.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:./database/data;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3"/>
```

I set database not to close automatically because I am using a shutdown hook , that commits a transaction. And I also set the system to log all the SQL into the trace file. I can see in the file that the database recieves all the SQL commands.

my hook

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            if(main!=null)
            {
                main.Disconnect();
            }
            try
            {
                PersistenceHandler.em.getTransaction().commit();
                PersistenceHandler.em.createQuery("SHUTDOWN COMPACT").executeUpdate();
                PersistenceHandler.em.close();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try
            {
               Config.Write();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }
    });
```

This does work on my machine , but does not work on another rather sluggish machine.

Comment: How are you shutting down the JVM?

Comment: System.exit(0) that way

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your approach is probably wrong. Transactions should be committed when a piece of DB-related code executes successfully. Doing a `commit` in a shutdown hook is like saying "Hey, I don't care if the house just burned down, let's go play in the living room."

That said, the `commit` probably has no effect since most frameworks will roll back any failed transaction. But these effects depend on the other parts of your design, like the Spring framework and the `Transactional` annotation to work correctly. If you're not using Spring, then you probably should.

So what you really should do instead is to wrap every "database change" (i.e. every command that the user can invoke via the UI) in a "transaction bracket": Open the transaction when the user sends the command and commit just before you return the result to the UI.

Comment: I considered that , the data changes are based not UI but on data recived by API , which can be up to 7 times per second per persistent object. The problem is not that transactions fail , but the fact the database changes remain memory and not written to disk drive.

Comment: So you need to create a transaction every time you receive data by API and commit when the change is good.